# LDAP - write concern / guaranteed write to replicas prior to return

Tags: ldap, replication

Is OpenLDAP (or are any of LDAP's flavors) capable of providing write concern? I know it's an eventually consistent model, but there's more then a few DB's that have eventual consistency + write concern.

After doing some research, I'm still not able to figure out whether or not it's a thing.

Answer (score 3):

The UnboundID Directory Server provides support for an assured replication mode in which you can request that the server delay the response to an operation until it has been replicated in a manner that satisfies your desired constraints.  This can be controlled on a per-operation basis by including a special control in the add/delete/modify/modify DN request, or by configuring the server with criteria that can be used to identify which operations should use this assured replication mode (e.g., you can configure the server so that operations targeting a particular set of attributes are subjected to a greater level of assurance than others).

Our assured replication implementation allows you to define separate requirements for local servers (servers in the same data center as the one that received the request from the client) and nonlocal servers (servers in other data centers).  This allows you tune the server to achieve a balance between performance and behavior.

For local servers, the possible assurance levels are:

- Do not perform any special assurance processing.  The server will send the response to the client as soon as it's processed locally, and the change will be replicated to other servers as soon as possible.  It is possible (although highly unlikely) that a permanent failure that occurs immediately after the server sends the response to the client but before it gets replicated could cause the change to be lost.
- Delay the response to the client until the change has been replicated to at least one other server in the local data center.  This ensures that the change will not be lost even in the event of the loss of the instance that the client was communicating with, but the change may not yet be visible on all instances in the local data center by the time the client receives the response.
- Delay the response to the client until the result of the change is visible in all servers in the local data center.  This ensures that no client accessing local servers will see out-of-date information.

The assurance options available for nonlocal servers are:

- Do not perform any special assurance processing.  The server will not delay the response to the client based on any communication with nonlocal servers, but a change could be lost or delayed if an entire data center is lost (e.g., by a massive natural disaster) or becomes unavailable (e.g., because it loses network connectivity).
- Delay the response to the client until the change has been replicated to at least one other server in at least one other data center.  This ensures that the change will not be lost even if a full data center is lost, but does not guarantee that the updated information will be visible everywhere by the time the client receives the response.
- Delay the response to the client until the change has been replicated to at least one server in every other data center.  This ensures that the change will be processed in every data center even if a network partition makes a data center unavailable for a period of time immediately after the change is processed.  But again this does not guarantee that the updated information will be visible everywhere by the time the client receives the response.
- Delay the response to the client until the change is visible in all available servers in all other data centers.  This ensures that no client will see out-of-date information regardless of the location of the server they are using.

The UnboundID Directory Server also provides features to help ensure that clients are not exposed to out-of-date information under normal circumstances.  Our replication mechanism is very fast so that changes generally appear everywhere in a matter of milliseconds.  Each server is constantly monitoring its own replication backlog and can take action if the backlog becomes too great (e.g., mild action like alerting administrators or more drastic measures like rejecting client requests until replication has caught up).  And because most replication backlogs are encountered when the server is taken offline for some reason, the server also has the ability to delay accepting connections from clients at startup until it has caught up with all changes processed in the environment while it was offline.  And if you further combine this with the advanced load-balancing and health checking capabilities of the UnboundID Directory Proxy Server, you can ensure that client requests are only forwarded to servers that don't have a replication backlog or any other undesirable condition that may cause the operation to fail, take an unusually long time to complete, or encounter out-of-date information.

Comment: Great, which flavor of ldap is this? And do we know if this in particular works for other flavors as well?

Comment: It's the UnboundID Directory Server, which is a commercial LDAP server implementation (with support for other directory services protocols like SCIM and a REST-based API).  Assured replication is not a standard LDAP feature, and the implementation we have is one that we have designed and implemented ourselves.  I don't know which (if any) other LDAP servers might offer similar features or how they might compare with the implementation that we provide.

Answer (score 2):

From reviewing RFC3384 discussion of replication requirements with respect to LDAP, it looks as though LDAP only requires eventual consistency and does not require transactional consistency. Therefore any products which support this feature are likely to do this with vendor specific implementations.

CA Directory does support a proprietary replication model called MULTI-WRITE which guarantees that the client obtains write confirmation only after all replicated instances have been updated. In addition it supports the standard X.525 Shadowing Protocol which provides lesser consistency guarantees and better performance.

With typical LDAP implementations, an update request will normally return immediately when the DSA handling this request has been updated, and not when the replica instances have been updated.  This is the case with OpenLDAP I believe. The benefits are speed, the downsides are lack of guarantee that an updated has been applied to all replicas.

Answer (score -2):

[CA's directory](http://www.ca.com/us/securecenter/ca-directory.aspx) product uses a Memory Mapped system and writes are so fast this is not a concern.

Comment: Why does speed guarantee a write or alleviate the need for a guaranteed write?

Comment: How do either memory mapping or fast writes guarantee replication? Answer doesn't even make sense, let alone answer the question.